# Improve image load time

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a few `img` tags whose `src` is changed `onmouseover`. This takes an inordinate amount of time to load. How can I improve the load time? The images are basically just different icons.

Comment: You can preload your images.

Comment: Try using [image sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Good point. That's a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a few things.

1) [CSS Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) is probably the preferred method.

2) You can load the images in a div and set that div to display none, making it so the images are already loaded so on mouseover they'll be there instantly.

Also [here's a link](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/even-better-image-preloading-with-css2) on how to PreLoad images with CSS

Comment: Tyler, your second method was perfect. You are going to get the accept. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it, the ideal solution in your case would be to use CSS sprites considering they're icons. However, depending on the situation sometimes sprites aren't ideal.

Here's one solution using JavaScript to preload images:

```
var images = new Array();

function preload() {
  for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
  }
}

preload(
  'http://image-1.jpg',
  'http://image-2.jpg',
  'http://image-3.jpg'
);
```

Comment: Meh… why bother with JS?

Comment: Because sometimes it's a better solution? It's hard to assess exactly what solution he needs with no example or code

Comment: Yes, obviously, tho here JS is unnecessary. Obviously he needs to preload it, whatever the method.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is achieve a rollover. It is strange that you'd experience a very long delay in this process. Usually, if the images aren't stored in some remote location, they're pretty fast.

Look at [this](http://www.saypoint.net/2011/04/creat-simple-image-rollover-html-code.html) article for some guidance

Other things you could try:
- sprites in css
- you could use two overlapping divs and hide one and unhide the other and vice versa